# Azure MSSQL Database Memory Optimization Error

Tags: sql-server, azure

I am using MSSQL Database in Azure, S0 Standard tier. I wanted to try the memory optimization for faster performance.

If I try it by creating a new database by creating tables, the error I get is:

**Msg 155, Level 15, State 1, Line 39
'MEMORY_OPTIMIZED' is not a recognized CREATE TABLE option.**

And if I try to set the memory optimization on the existing database and existing tables, when I do the right click on a table and click the Advisor tool, I get this error:

**Operation not supported on version 12.0.1700 SqlAzureDatabase. (Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlEnum)
For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&LinkId=20476**

Ideas? :(

Answer (score 0):

Memory Optimized tables aren't supported on Basic or Standard pricing tiers.